# ¿Hay alguna expresión en castellano para "rule of thumb"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

En inglés se utiliza con frecuencia la expresión "rule of thumb" para definir *un principio o criterio de amplia aplicación que no es necesariamente preciso ni fiable en toda situación* ([Wikipedia dixit](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb)).

Leo en la Wikipedia (mismo enlace que antes) que:

> La traducción literal es “regla del pulgar” y parece tener su origen
>   en la práctica de los antiguos carpinteros, quienes usaban su pulgar
>   en lugar de una regla para realizar mediciones.
>
> En español una frase más aproximada es “a ojo de buen cubero”, que
>   quiere expresar que se realiza una aproximación basada en la
>   experiencia. Otra expresión idiomática común es “regla práctica”,
>   “regla general” o “regla de oro”, es decir, una regla que sirve o se
>   aplica a la mayoría de los casos.

A mí me gusta especialmente "a ojo de buen cubero", pero me pregunto: ¿qué otras expresiones se utilizan para este concepto? ¿es correcto usar el anglicismo hablando en castellano?

Comment: ¿Usar "El sentido común"? ¿Talvez?

Comment: "por norma general" también se usa bastante, yo creo que más que "regla general". La expresión "a ojo de buen cubero" se suele aplicar a medidas, cantidades, etc, por ejemplo cuando haces una receta y echas los ingredientes "a ojo de buen cubero", sin pesarlos o medirlos.

Comment: A mí me suena las expresión ***"a ojo"***, que supongo que viene de "a ojo de buen cubero".

Comment: Aunque he visto la traducción "literal" de "regla del dedo gordo", me inclino por el ojo del buen cubero, pero se puede abreviar por "a ojo cubero".

Comment: Estoy en total desacuerdo con la definición que encuentras en wikipedia. Una cosa es hacer las cosas al bulto, a ojímetro o a ojo de buen cubero y otra muy diferente aplicar una "regla general". El "ojo de buen cubero" depende de la persona mientras que la "rule of thumb" es algo generalmente aceptado como una _"goto solution"_ o una solución que siempre aplica sin necesidad de _tirarle mucha cabeza._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según [linguee.com](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/rule+of+thumb.html), lo más típico es traducirlo por "regla general":

> It appears that there is a rule of thumb for this purpose.
>   Parece haber una regla general para este propósito.

Como sucede tan a menudo en nuestro idioma, expresiones como ésta suelen diferir entre regiones geográficas. Por ejemplo en mi caso, en Chile, jamás había escuchado la frase "a ojo de buen cubero".

Según [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=regla+general%2Cregla+de+oro%2C+norma+general&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cregla%20general%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bregla%20general%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRegla%20general%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cregla%20de%20oro%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bregla%20de%20oro%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRegla%20de%20Oro%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRegla%20de%20oro%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BREGLA%20DE%20ORO%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnorma%20general%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnorma%20general%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNorma%20general%3B%2Cc0), es más común "regla general" que "norma general" o "regla de oro" <sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1: Es importante señalar que ese Ngrams no aplica totalmente a esta discusión, pues incluirá todas las apariciones de esas frases, las que no siempre querrán decir lo mismo que la frase inglesa que nos ocupa en esta pregunta.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

"Por norma general" también se usa bastante en España, o "como regla general". El uso del anglicismo no es común y puede sonar extraño a la mayoría de los hablantes.

La expresión "a ojo de buen cubero" yo la traduciria como "aproximadamente" y se suele aplicar a medidas, cantidades, etc. Por ejemplo cuando haces una receta y echas los ingredientes "a ojo de buen cubero", los echas sin pesarlos o medirlos.

Answer (score 3):

Si imagino que estoy dando un *rule of thumb* a alguien, creo que diría:

> Te voy a dar *una regla básica* que te puede servir en estos casos.
>
> Te voy a dar *un tip* que te será útil para estos casos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la traducción como "**regla práctica**" que se propone (entre otras) en Wikipedia traduce mejor el concepto de ["**Rule of thumb**"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb)

> "Establece una especie de fórmula u observación generalmente aceptada como conocimiento práctico basado en la experiencia, sin embargo no se trata de una proposición científica.
>
> Es un procedimiento de fácil aprendizaje, destinado a recordar o calcular aproximadamente un valor o tomar una decisión."

Y, en mi experiencia, la "*rule of thumb*" de los sastres (dos veces el perímetro del pulgar = perimetro de la muñeca; dos veces el perímetro de la muñeca = perimetro del cuello; dos veces el perímetro del cuello = perimetro de la cintura y dos veces el perímetro de la cintura = estatura) supone una aproximación sorprendentemente buena.

Answer (score 1):

Tiene el mismo significado que la expresión ["al ojo por ciento"](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Proverbios_venezolanos#A) utilizada en Venezuela o "al ojo del un buen cubero" en otros países hispanos. Y no es una regla *per se*, sino una expresión que denota rapididez para medir o calcular algo. Es básicamente un cálculo aproximado por estimación.

En el caso angloparlante también denota facilidad y simpleza para hacer algo. Ellos le dicen "rule" refiriéndose a dictamen judicial, aunque la mayoría ignora ese carácter y piensa que en hecho es una regla o método. Es confuso por qué fue un dictamen que determinaba un método.

Answer (score 1):

También se usa la expresión **a ojímetro**, que, con sentido del humor, le da a la imprecisión un aire técnico.

> [**ojímetro**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qy1vyIa)
>
> De ojo y ‒́metro.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Capacidad de hacer con rapidez un cálculo aproximado.
>
> a ojímetro
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. a bulto.

En Chile decimos *al ojímetro* (con *al* en vez de *a*).

Comment: Me perece que no estoy muy cerca de "rule of thumb", pero agregué esta expresión porque se acerca un poco a lo que otros usuarios han ido respondiendo.

Comment: Aquí en España también se usa bastante, decimos [_a ojímetro_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qy1vyIa). ¿Decís vosotros _a_ o _al_?

Comment: Decimos "al ojo" y "al ojímetro".

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por la referencia, la agregué.

Comment: En Colombia se ha vuelto popular usar "**a ojímetro**"

Answer (score -1):

Rule of thumb tiene un sentido muy particular en las areas tecnicas y de ingenieria. La frase equivalente es "Regla de la mano derecha" que tiene exactamente el mismo origien y signifado que rule of thumb. Es una nemotecnia que trasciende el campo en el que se usa, ya que el gatillo de memoria esta en tu mano, por lo que siempre podras recordar la regla aplicable, por eso la acepcion de "regla general"

Del artículo de la Wikipedia sobre [Regla de la mano derecha](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_la_mano_derecha):

> La regla de la mano derecha o del sacacorchos es un método para determinar direcciones vectoriales, y tiene como base los planos cartesianos. Se emplea prácticamente en dos maneras; para direcciones y movimientos vectoriales lineales, y para movimientos y direcciones rotacionales. Se usa para determinar tambien el sentido de una corriente electrica inducida por un campo magnetico.

[image: Regla de la mano derecha]

Comment: En mis libros de física a eso le llaman en inglés "right-hand rule" en vez de "rule of thumb".

Comment: Sí. [_Rule of thumb_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb) hace referencia a una regla general, basada en la experiencia, sin prejuicio de excepciones particulares. No es lo mismo que la regla de la mano derecha.